# How do I modify the interval for cleanup tasks in Publishing Service?

Tags: publishing-service

We have a situation where the application pool hosting the Publishing Service is configured to restart every day at the same time (3am).

What can I do to ensure that tasks are run at least once during that window?

Comment: Hi Michael, can you add more details to the question. It will help readers to understand the problem statement, the need for the change and how your answers address the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following recycling conditions:

[image: Recycling conditions]

Create a new configuration file in the Publishing Service directory, such as the following:

`D:\Sites\sps\sitecoreruntime\_shared\config\sc.publishing.web.command.services.xml`

Here we want to reduce the interval time to every 4 hours and reduce the retention on the job age.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Settings>
  <Commands>
    <Web>
      <Services>
        <Add>
          <Scheduler>
            <Options>
              <Tasks>
                <PublishJobCleanUp>
                  <TaskDefinition>
                    <Options>
                      <JobAge>1.00:00:00</JobAge>
                    </Options>
                  </TaskDefinition>
                  <TriggerDefinitions>
                     <Interval>
                      <Options Interval="4:00:00" />
                    </Interval>
                  </TriggerDefinitions>
                </PublishJobCleanUp>
                <PublishOperationAgeBasedCleanUp>
                  <TaskDefinition>
                    <Options>
                      <PublisherOperationAge>1.00:00:00</PublisherOperationAge>
                    </Options>
                  </TaskDefinition>
                  <TriggerDefinitions>
                    <Interval>
                      <Options Interval="04:00:00" />
                    </Interval>
                  </TriggerDefinitions>
                </PublishOperationAgeBasedCleanUp>
              </Tasks>
            </Options>
          </Scheduler>
        </Add>
      </Services>
    </Web>
  </Commands>
</Settings>
```